# How to run the build in GitHub Actions itself?

Tags: java, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

```
name: demo
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'pipeline-dev'

jobs:
  conditional_step:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-20.04'
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: hello-world-with-gradle
    - run: cd /home/runner/work/test-actions/test-actions
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        distribution: temurin
        java-version: 8
        
    - name: Setup Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
    
    - name: Execute Gradle build
      run: ./gradlew build
```

The above workflow gives a JAR as as a build for Application. Now do we have the capabilities to run this JAR in the workflow itself?
like

```
- run: Java -jar hello-world-0.1.0.jar   // This gives an error
```

In our real use case we want to run the utility in pipeline and send its output result to other google bucket.

Tried out various java actions plugins but not able to run JAR yet. If anyone know how to run a JAR or any other alternative It would be helpful.

Comment: What’s the error message you’re seeing?

Comment: Does your gradle build use non-standard settings? Usually the jar is in the `build/libs/` directory, so you might have to run as `java -jar build/libs/hello-world-0.1.0.jar`

Comment: @Julia Error message is : Java command not found.
Although Java is present as it did build the project & gave JAR.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I did change the directory to build/libs/ before executing that command. Verified by doing a ls in that directory and JAR was present there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if the case matters, use `java`, not `Java`:

```
- run: java -jar hello-world-0.1.0.jar 
      ^^^
```

That way, the GitHub runner should find and execute `java` after applying [`actions/setup-java`](https://github.com/actions/setup-java).

Comment: @Mohit No problem. With a Windows GitHub runner, it might have worked, but by default, the runners are Linux-base, case-sensitive.

Comment: oh ok got that point 